# python argparse default arguments versus given arguments

Tags: python, argparse

Using python 3.8 argparse:

```
def_value= 'whatever'
argParser.add_argument ("-w", "--whatever", type=str, nargs=1, default=def_value, help="Whatever. Defaults to %s"  % def_value)
args= argParser.parse_args()
print (args.whatever)
```

If I call my program passing a option -w with a value, args.whatever is a list. I mean:

```
myprog -w just_a_test
[just_a_test]
```

but, I pass nothing, the default argument is a string.

```
myprog
whatever
```

This is annoying, I mean, I have to test the type of args.whatever before using it;
If it is a is a string, just use it as string; if it is a list, I have to use it as args.whatever[0], you see ?

What is the best way to deal with such thing ?

PS: I think it is specific to 3.x, as I recall 2.x returned strings all the time.

Comment: You can make `def_value` a list?

Comment: Or you could omit `nargs` then you'll always get a string

Comment: why did you specify `nargs=1`?  Do you understand what that does?

Comment: @sabik: Its the best move in my case. Thank you.

Comment: @hpaulj: Aparently, no ! Thanks, removing nargs fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try to remove the nargs option?

Comment: I did it now. Easy fix ever. I copy/past and didn't realize nargs caused this.

Answer (score 1):

using n_args parameter will wrap the value in a list, therefore, there are two options:
1.
remove nargs argument.

```
def_value= 'whatever'
argParser.add_argument("-w", "--whatever", type=str, default=def_value, help="Whatever. Defaults to %s"  % def_value)
args= argParser.parse_args()
print(args.whatever)
```

argparse by default allows only one arg, so in this case, no matter passing an argument or not, you will always get a string, and you will get an error when you try to pass more than 1 value.

2.wrap def_value with a list:

```
def_value= ['whatever']
argParser.add_argument("-w", "--whatever", type=str, nargs=1, default=def_value, help="Whatever. Defaults to %s"  % def_value)
args= argParser.parse_args()
print(args.whatever)
```

now both default and passed in value will be a list with a single string, and it will also raise an error when you pass more than 1 value.

Both solutions above should accomplish the same goal, depending on which you prefer

Comment: I've copy/paste from other line and didn't realize nargs cause this behaviour. Removing the nargs is the best move in my case. Thank you.